# ErrorException : Array to string conversion during php artisan migrate:fresh

Tags: laravel, laravel-migrations

Trying to set a column as a dateTime type, and to default as the current time and date. However, I keep getting the Error mentioned in the title...

This issue in question is related to the 'dateAccepted' field, the 'dateSubmitted' will probably also have this issue too, but I havent attempted that yet.

Am I using the wrong data type? or just coded wrong..? All advice welcome.
(P.S new to the site, apologies for formatting)

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('adoption_requests', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->bigInteger('userid')->unsigned();
        $table->bigInteger('animalID')->unsigned();
        $table->date('dateSubmitted');
        $table->dateTime('dateAccepted')->default(getdate())->nullable();
        $table->date('requestAccepted');
        $table->date('staffID');
        $table->timestamps();
        //$table->boolean('$adoptionStatus')->default(0);
        $table->foreign('userid')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->foreign('animalID')->references('id')->on('animals');

    });
}
```

```
    ErrorException  : Array to string conversion

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\AAS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Schema\Grammars\Grammar.php:248
    244|         }
    245|
    246|         return is_bool($value)
    247|                     ? "'".(int) $value."'"
  > 248|                     : "'".(string) $value."'";
    249|     }
    250|
    251|     /**
    252|      * Create an empty Doctrine DBAL TableDiff from the Blueprint.

  Exception trace:

  1   Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::handleError("Array to string conversion", "C:\xampp\htdocs\AAS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Schema\Grammars\Grammar.php", [])
      C:\xampp\htdocs\AAS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Schema\Grammars\Grammar.php:248

  2   Illuminate\Database\Schema\Grammars\Grammar::getDefaultValue()
      C:\xampp\htdocs\AAS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Schema\Grammars\MySqlGrammar.php:946

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$table->dateTime('dateAccepted')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
```

this may help

**Edit**

Explanation:

function `gettime()` retuns an array. So you can't store an array of values in `datetime` column. you're gonna need a `datetime`.

One other way than the original answer is,

```
$table->dateTime('dateAccepted')->default(now()->toDateTimeString());
```

Comment: Please explain why

Comment: getdate() outputs array. And being assigned to a dateTime which is a string